# How to make Form move inside panel edge bounds?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make my second form. When it opens and it moves inside some panel bounds, I don't want it to be hidden between edges.

```cs
Form3 objForm = new Form3();
objForm.TopLevel = false;
panel4.Controls.Add(objForm);
objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
objForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
objForm.Show();
```

Comment: any answer?.....

Comment: guys is that possible why none answer until now